# Storing an int into a char array

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I have these set up at the top of the method.

```
public static String eval(char[] postfix) {

    StackInterface<Character> stack = new LinkedStack<>();

    char[] answer = new char[postfix.length];

    int numOne = 0;
    int numTwo = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < postfix.length; i++)
    .....
```

Down the line I have done this:

```
    if (!stack.empty()) {
       numOne = stack.top();
       stack.pop();

       numTwo = stack.peek();
       stack.pop();

       //My problem is here. I can't push the result to my char[] array.

       if (postfix[i] == '+') {
           result = numOne + numTwo;
           stack.push(result);
       ..........
```

How do I set it up so that I can push the result of the two `pop()`'d variables to my `char[]` array?

Answer (score 1):

You need too read them as Character (or char),  not int;
The stack is working with Character, there is no reason to read the values into integer.
Like:

```
char numOne = 0;
char numTwo = 0;
char result = 0;
...
 result = numOne + numTwo;
 stack.push(result);
```

Note, there could be additional problem with the char range of the sum result.